# BaseHTTPServer thread does not work

Tags: python, multithreading

My code is simple. Using BaseHTTPServer and ThreadInMix I want to run
a python script (Script1.py) for every request made simultaneously.

My Code-

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import time

def simple_script(self):
   print 'simple_script'
   s = Popen('C:/Python27/python C:/Script1.py 5', shell=True,
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   out, err = s.communicate()
   print out, err
   self.wfile.write(out)

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_GET(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.end_headers()
       self.wfile.write('{0}\n'.format(time.asctime()))
       simple_script(self)
       return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
   pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 8080), Handler)
   print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
   server.serve_forever()

"""
# C:/Script1.py
import time, sys

s = time.time()

while True:
   if time.time() - s > int(sys.argv[1]):
       break
   else:
       time.sleep(1)
       print time.asctime()
"""
```

I just found out that-
With URL: http://localhost:8080
If I open multiple tabs/browsers for IE, this works JUST FINE
But,

If I open multiple tabs/pages in Chrome or Firefox, the pages wait for previous page? This does not imply threading in Chrome or Firefox? Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me:

Starting server, use  to stop
localhost.localdomain - - [03/Oct/2011 16:25:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
simple_script
localhost.localdomain - - [03/Oct/2011 16:25:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
simple_script
Mon Oct  3 16:25:56 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:57 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:58 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:59 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:26:00 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:26:01 2011

Mon Oct  3 16:25:56 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:57 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:58 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:25:59 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:26:00 2011
Mon Oct  3 16:26:01 2011

Comment: Hi Ringding,
Can you please tell me which browser you used to trigger your requests?

Comment: Hi Ringding,
I have updated the code based on my need!! Can you please try it again and let me know if it works?

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I get it. But have you tried it with Firefox or Chrome? The same time comes only for IE, not Firefox and Chrome!! If you look at the comment by frnknstn http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/12/pymotw-basehttpserver.html, you will note that the firefox sends 2nd requests only if 1st request is executed. Do you know the reason? Thanks!!

Comment: My Firefox behaves the same way. Normally, Firefox will allow a number (usually small, but >1) of concurrent connections per server. Apparently, this doesn’t apply when two URLs are exactly the same (supposedly including relevant headers such as cookies). You can trick it by appending some garbage; open http://<host>:<port>/g1 in one tab and http://<host>:<port>/g2 in another one. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: Great, I just tested it!! It works just the way you mentioned. That is great!! Do you know any settings on Firefox that makes it work normal way?? Thanks